# React returning multiple element without creating a container element

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way in react to return multiple elements without creating a extra element that contain the children?
So I can write a function as follow:

```
function renderRows(){
return (
   <div className="row">Row1</div>
   <div className="row">Row1</div>
   <div className="row">Row1</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.Fragment` like this:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

... 

render() { 
  return(
    <Fragment>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </Fragment>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) for this.

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="row">Row1</div>
      <div className="row">Row1</div>
      <div className="row">Row1</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

There is also a shorthand syntax for this `<></>`, but its not supported in all tools. Try it

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">Row1</div>
      <div className="row">Row1</div>
      <div className="row">Row1</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Check the live demo [here](https://codepen.io/reactjs/pen/VrEbjE?editors=1000)